# How to add class to a jQuery element if a condition is true and remove the same class if the condition is false?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a shorter way to do the following?

```
var select_all_checkbox = $("input.select_all");
var is_checked = select_all_checkbox.prop("checked");

if (is_checked) {
    select_all_checkbox.parent().addClass("selected");
} else {
    select_all_checkbox.parent().removeClass("selected");
}
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Use [`toggleClass`](https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/#toggleClass-className-switch), passing a second argument (a boolean) that specifies whether the class should be added or not:

```
select_all_checkbox.parent().toggleClass("selected", is_checked);
```

---

If you have multiple elements selected by `input.select_all`, you have to iterate over them though:

```
$("input.select_all").each(function() {
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('selected', this.checked);
});
```

Comment: It doesn’t really lead to the same effect.

Comment: I think OP is expecting the `is_checked` boolean to auto-update itself. Perhaps you would want to update the boolean whenever the checkbox is changed, via the `.change()` event...

Comment: Because toggleClass will always add the class if it is not present and remove it otherwise. The addClass/removeClass methods, on the contrary, will make no changes to the element’s classes if addClass is run on an element that already has the class (or if removeClass is run on an element that does not have the class).

Comment: @aruseni: I updated my answer to be more clear. Have a look at the documentation of `toggleClass`. It accepts a boolean as second argument.

Comment: You dig into the details of a **particular example**. But it’s just an example, and it’s not actually what the question is about. The question is about writing code that does exactly the same as the original code. If you use toggleClass, you change this behavior significantly and the code will not work as expected in some specific cases. Note that I’m not saying this is executed on checkbox change! Imagine it executing in a callback function that can be called multiple times with the same state of the checkbox. Do you now see why the toggleClass is sort of useless in such scenario?

Comment: .toggle() is definitely the way to go in this case.

Comment: @aruseni: I'm not sure I follow I didn't focus on any specific example. If you call `toggleClass` class with the same state twice, it will simply not add or remove the class. I think you have a misunderstanding of how this particular form of `toggleClass` works. If you look at the implementation, you will see that it basically does the same thing as you wrote in your answer: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/b8d0d54a3c4960794a1b492957abeb56eddd1e48/src/attributes/classes.js#L101

Comment: @aruseni: Maybe I wasn't clear enough: If you pass the state as second argument and it is `true`, `toggleClass` will add the classes. If the state is `false`, `toggleValue` will remove the classes. That is **exactly** the same thing as calling `addClass` when the state is `true` and `removeClass` when the state is `false`. `toggleClass` **does not** alternately toggle the classes when a state is passed as second argument.

Comment: Wow. Actually, you’re right, that does work as expected. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

Absolutely! You can choose between the methods (addClass/removeClass) programmatically, and use the one that is returned when an expression is executed.

Like this:

```
var select_all_checkbox = $("input.select_all");
var is_checked = select_all_checkbox.prop("checked");

select_all_checkbox.parent()[is_checked ? "addClass" : "removeClass"]("selected");
```

Comment: Here is in coffeescript: $('.some-selector')[if isChecked then 'addClass' else 'removeClass'] 'selected'

Comment: while not as clean as using `toggleClass`, this is a pretty neat method nonetheless